# Minimize buffering when using audio element

Tags: html, audio, opus

I'm sending Opus audio to a browser and I need it to play almost instantly. I am using an audio element like this:

```
<audio src="/stream.opus" autoplay  preload="auto" type="audio/opus" controls />
```

This seems to require ~4 seconds before it starts playing the audio. I would like something closer to 100ms. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried using the buffered dom element http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_buffered.asp

Comment: forget that, use the web audio api. here is an article with a good intro to it http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/

Comment: here is a fiddle of webaudio http://jsfiddle.net/thingsinjars/eLqU5/500/

Comment: Seems great at a first glance. Will implement it in my app and get back accept.

Comment: This does not seem to work when streaming. Of what I can see request.response is undefined while reading data from the server.